# The value of the variable from the first function is not reflected in the value of the second

Tags: javascript

I'm writing to you about the fact that the value given by the ".bottom_down i" function of the heigths variable is not reflected for ".bottom_up i". Help please, I'm new to Js

```js
var heights = 0;
$('.bottom_up i').click(function () {
 heights = heights - window.innerHeight;
 window.scrollTo(300, heights);
 alert('Bottom_up ='+ heights);
 $('.bottom_down').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1200);
 if (heights = window.innerHeight){
  $('.bottom_up').animate({opacity: '0'}, 1200);
 }else{
  $('.bottom_up').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1200);
 }
 return false;
});
$('.bottom_down i').click(function () {
        heights = heights + window.innerHeight;
        window.scrollTo(300, heights);
        $('.bottom_up').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1200);
        alert('Bottom_down ='+ heights);
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()) {
  $('.bottom_down').animate({opacity: '0'}, 1200);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (heights = window.innerHeight){
```

Instead of checking if both values are equal with an equality operator, you are assigning `heights` the value of `window.innerHeight`.

It should be like this:

```
if (heights == window.innerHeight){
```

Consider using a linter to avoid this type of errors, for example, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/)